# Crossed NE and SE arrows?

Tags: arrows, fractions

I'm trying to write a piece of code in LaTeX which includes a crossed set of arrows (the \nearrow and \searrow). Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begindocument
$$\dfrac{5}{12}\makebox[0pt][l]{$\,\,\nearrow$}\searrow \dfrac{20}{9}.$$
\end{document}
```

The code is doing what I want it to do but I am noticing errors, namely

> unclosed $$ found at $
> unclosed open group { found at $
> unexpected $ after open group {
> unexpected $ after $$
> unexpected $ after $$

I can't seem to understand how to resolve this and get the symbol I'm looking for. After some research I learnt about a \toea command but I can't seem to implement this. Any help would be great!

Comment: I noticed I haven't included the list of packages I've used in my code but I have all the standard ones you'd expect

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do also replace `\begindocument` with `\begin{document}`, and please peruse and take to heart the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Comment: if  you fix `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \begindocument` you get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 $$\dfrac` the message you do show is not from tex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these composite arrows will never show up in first- or second-level subscripts or superscripts (or, more generally, while TeX is in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` math mode), the following solution, which creates a macro called `\crossedarrows` with the help of the low-level `\ooalign` command, may be of interest to you.

[image]

Note that the definition of `\crossedarrows` assumes that the new symbol is to be used as a relational operator (hence the `\mathrel` directive). If, instead, the symbol should be used as a binary operator, you should change `\mathrel` to `\mathbin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\crossedarrows{\mathrel%  % or '\mathbin' ?
    {\ooalign{$\nearrow$\cr$\searrow$}}}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \frac{5}{12} \crossedarrows \frac{20}{9} $
\end{document}
```